# Pic18f65k22 writing 2 bytes to a un unsigned char when assigning a value

Tags: pic

I am using pic18f65k22 and mplabx with pic kit 3.

I have an unsigned char variable sim_reg.
When i assign it a value of 0x01 it writes to two consecutive bytes instead of 1 .so it over writes my next variable hence causing a havoc.

The assignment instruction is sim_reg=0x01 and its disassembly is

```
Movlw 0x1
Movlb 0x2
Movwf count,banked
```

But it affects two consecutive bytes

Comment: Could this be a problem with the extended set enabled modifying the instruction? - see section 29.2.3, page 478 of the manual

Comment: Extended set is disabled in the compiler (c18) settings.

Comment: It's difficult to imagine a more serious error, which makes me think it's much more likely that the context is important. Can you post the smallest compilable code snippet that exhibits this error?

Comment: I cant reproduce it outside the context of the application. I tried reproducing it on a sample code but it didnt occur. Nor does it occur for any other variable.  If it helps , sim_reg is location at location 513. Means its first byte of bank 2. Does it make any difference ? I read on the manual "bank changes are error prone".

Comment: @MuhammadAli Posting the whole C source code will help us help you..

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the whole source . its company proprietary. I can share map file if its of any help.

Comment: What are your compiler optimisation settings?

Comment: Optimizarion: Debug friendly.

Comment: Are you sure it affects two consecutive bytes? MOVLW 0x01 puts the eight-bit value 0x01 into W, MOVLB 0x02 puts the low nybble of 0x02 (which is 0x02) into the BSR (bank select register) and MOVWF count, banked puts W into the 'count' location of bank 'banked'. It all looks 8-bit to me.

Comment: What does the dissassembly immediately before & after look like? Have you single-asm-instruction stepped through that code and seen the other memory location change at exactly that point?

Comment: @AdamLawrence yes i am sure it affects two consecutive bytes. Acc to map file. 513 location is of sim_reg and 514 is of an array. When i write to sim_reg the first index of that array has its value overwritten to a null (0).

Comment: @brhans no i haven't single stepped in asm. And unfortunately the problem is gone . so i dont have asm anymore. The problem disappeared automatically . all i did was change the location of sim_reg.

Comment: The problem was also bypassed by giving the sim_reg 2 bytes for itself. I-e making it an int. So it wont overwrite my array

Comment: Although the problem is gone for now. But i am curious as how did it occur. Because it might sting me again if its me doing something wrong. Or even if compiler is making it a hell for me.